# ¿Por qué Google Chrome me agrega el tag tbody?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Tengo dos tablas que se crean y se van llenando a través de un evento.

Tengo diseñado el estilo de la tabla para que las fila pares se pinten de blanco:

```
table {

border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;

}

td, th {
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Pero debido a que Chrome me agrega un tbody por cada tag `<tr>` en la primera tabla(back-end) no me funciona el css.

La primera tabla se llena de datos desde el back-end:

```
var prueba = {};
        prueba = nuevaCadena[nuevaCadena.length - 1].replace(/<br>/g, "").split(",");
        prueba.venta = prueba[0];
        prueba.fecha = prueba[1];
        prueba.heladeria = prueba[2];

        //prueba.base.split(",");

        //if (myElem === null) {
        var contenido = document.getElementById("contenido");
        var tr2 = document.createElement("TR");


        if (contenido.getElementsByTagName("TH").length === 0)
        {
            contenido.appendChild(tr2);
            tr2.innerHTML += "<th>Heladeria</th>";
            tr2.innerHTML += "<th>Fecha</th>";
            tr2.innerHTML += "<th>ID</th>";

        } else {
           var template = "<tr><td>{{heladeria}}</td><td>{{fecha}}</td><td>{{venta}}</td></tr>";

            document.querySelector('#contenido').innerHTML +=       Mustache.render(template, prueba);

       }
```

Y la segunda, que funciona perfectamente, toma los datos desde el tag `<select>`:

```
var contenido = document.getElementById("contenido2");
var tr2 = document.createElement("TR");

var tr = document.createElement("TR");
if (contenido.getElementsByTagName("TH").length === 0)
{
    contenido.appendChild(tr2);
    tr2.innerHTML += "<th>Heladeria</th>";
    tr2.innerHTML += "<th>Fecha</th>";
    tr2.innerHTML += "<th>Sabor</th>";
    tr2.innerHTML += "<th>Cantidad</th>";

}

//var head = document.createElement("TH");

contenido.appendChild(tr);

//var th = document.createElement("TD");
var option = ["heladerias", "sabores"];
var valor = document.getElementById("sabor_calorias");
var fecha = document.getElementById("fecha");


for (var i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {

    var input = document.getElementById(option[i]).selectedIndex;
    var input2 = document.getElementById(option[i]).options;

    tr.innerHTML += "<td>" + input2[input].text + "</td>";
    tr.innerHTML += "<td>" + fecha.value + "</td>";

    for (var j = 1; j <= 1; j++) {

        input = document.getElementById(option[j]).selectedIndex;
        input2 = document.getElementById(option[j]).options;
        tr.innerHTML += "<td>" + input2[input].text + "</td>";
        tr.innerHTML += "<td>" + valor.value + "</td>";
        tr.innerHTML += "<input type='button' class='borrar' value='x' onclick='deleted(this)'/>";

    }


}
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías poner el ejemplo real de la iteración que haces en la primera tabla, porque así como está puesto sólo generaría una fila (en este caso, las TH). ¿Qué hay dentro de los dos primeros TR?

Comment: No estoy seguro a lo que te referis, pero originalmente le quite el `else` , y claro esa es la idea que cree solo la fila-cabecera para que cuando vuelva a clickear no la cree de nuevo si esta creada salta a el siguiente codigo este el  `else` o no.

Comment: Dentro de los `tr`s estan las etiquetas Mustache.

Comment: Y qué pasa si pruebas creando cada fila igual como creas la cabecera? Mal que mal, igual estás creando el elemento `tr2`, el cual podrías adosar a la tabla para luego llenarlo con la salida de Mustache. Esto conlleva que a la plantilla tienes que quitarle el <tr> del inicio y final.

Comment: Ya lo solucione igual agregue en el html el `tbody` con un id y logre que funcione el CSS.

Answer (score 3):

http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/tables/tbody.html:

> El elemento TBODY define un grupo de filas de datos en una tabla. Una tabla debe tener uno o más elementos TBODY, que deben seguir por TFOOT opcional. La etiqueta final TBODY siempre es opcional. La etiqueta de inicio es opcional cuando la tabla contiene sólo un TBODY y no THEAD o TFOOT.

Osea, en simples palabras, el TBODY siempre esta ahí, aunque no lo hayas incluido. Y cuando este no se incluye el navegador debe corregirlo para poder armar el DOM.

Tomado de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements

Pero ayudando a resolver el problema, te dejo este codigo, espero te sirva.

```css
table {

border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;

}

td, th {
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1
      </td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>2
      </td>
    </tr><tr><td>3
      </td>
    </tr><tr><td>4
      </td>
    </tr><tr><td>5
      </td>
    </tr><tr><td>6
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Pero por que la segunda tabla no se le agrega el `tbody`

Comment: Ademas la tabla se crea con javascript .. ya lo habia visto el link de stackoverflow que me pasaste.. Gracias igual..

Comment: Si, el link, de la respuesta corresponde, pense que querias una respuesta en español. Sobre la pregunta, del comentario, yo iría más por la forma en como armas la tabla, en una tabla usas Mustage donde pasas el template al render y el resultado es la tabla con tbody, Y en la otra tabla (despues de alguna seleccion de un select, según indicas) la armas "appendeando" td's

Comment: Si, pense lo mismo pero no le encuentro solucion probe argregandole el `tbody` a la tabla pero no se soluciona el problema.. Además en tu código solo agregás filas y no columnas ...